# SVG masking not working in Firefox

Tags: firefox, svg

I am trying to add SVG mask on image using this:

```
.image {
  -webkit-mask-box-image: url('mask.svg');
  mask-border: url('mask.svg');
  clip-path: url(mask.svg);
}
```

and the actual mask/svg file is like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 320 300" style="enable-background:new 0 0 320 300;" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
    .st0{clip-path:url(#XMLID_5_);fill:#E1173D;}
</style>
<g id="XMLID_2_">
    <defs>
        <rect id="XMLID_3_" x="0.7" width="319.3" height="300"/>
    </defs>
    <clipPath id="XMLID_5_">
        <use xlink:href="#XMLID_3_"  style="overflow:visible;"/>
    </clipPath>
    <path id="XMLID_4_" class="st0" d="M320,149.1C320,61.3,252.5,0,158.1,0H37.6v247.9L1.2,296.5c-0.3,0.4-0.4,0.8-0.4,1.3
        c0,1.2,1,2.2,2.2,2.2h155.2C252.5,300,320,238.2,320,149.1"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

Now, this works great when viewed on Chrome, but nothing shows on Firefox (not to mention IE).

What am i doing wrong, any help would be great?

Answer (score 1):

The url must directly refer to a `<clipPath>` element by including its id as fragment identifier.

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path
- https://drafts.fxtf.org/css-masking-1/#the-clip-path